# Terminal command to know which gtk theme is in use

Tags: themes, gtk

Is there a terminal command to find out which `gtk` theme is being used and whether the theme is in `~/.themes` or in `/usr/share/themes`?

On running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`, I see `Greybird` which is the default theme in Xubuntu but I'm not using that; I'm using another theme called `Numix` which I've modified and am running from ~/.themes after renaming it to `MyNumix`.

```
[08:41 PM] ~ $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
'Greybird'
[08:41 PM] ~ $
```

Comment: The command in your question works for me on Ubuntu with the Unity DE.

Comment: @edwinksl OP account is deleted, best just to close this I think. Works for me to though